# Arithmetic overflow error when converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the following query:

```
SELECT 
  DU.MESSAGEINSERTDATE 
from [MYSMSREPORT].[DBO].[SIXDAYSHISTORY] 
where
  (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, MESSAGEINSERTDATE, 104), 112) 
  BETWEEN 
     CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, 01/08/2008, 104), 112) 
  AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,31/09/2012,104),112))
```

I have this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

What is the problem?

Comment: I edited your question to be more clear. Please review this edit.

Comment: 01/08/2008 is math, '01/08/2008' is a date

Comment: did you try single quotes around the dates?  `'01/08/2008'` and `'31/09/2012'`

Comment: In general, when you have more information to add, you should *edit* your existing question, not open a new one. I've voted to close the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599167/arithmetic-overflow-error-when-converting-expression-to-data-type-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

The 31st September isn't a date, so SQL cannot convert it to one.

As an aside you should hard code dates in a culture inspecific format (yyyyMMdd). `01/08/2012` may convert to 1st August on your Server, but run on another and it could be 8th January. 20120801 will convert to 1st August on **all** machines.

In addition Why are you converting dates to `NVARCHAR`? You are removing any benfit of indices you have, and also performing needless implicit and explicit conversions. Assuming `MESSAGEINSERTDATE` is a DATETIME Column you could just use

```
WHERE MESSAGEINSERTDATE BETWEEN '20120801' AND '20120930'
```

If you need to remove the time from `MESSAGEINSERTDATE` use

```
CAST(MESSAGEINSERTDATE AS DATE)
```

Comment: Rather than removing the time (which again negates any index usage), better would be `MESSAGEINSERTDATE >= '20120801' AND MESSAGEINSERTDATE < '20121001'` (i.e. switch to a semi-open interval)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - `CAST( AS DATE)` [is sargable](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable)

Comment: Check the execution plan [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56abb/2). The index is used despite using `CAST( AS DATE)`.